# IndexError: list index out of range: When changing code format

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, max

The original code is:

```
def lucky_candies(a, k):
    l = [0] + (k-1) * [float('-inf')]
    for x in a:
        l = [max(l[(i-x) % k] + x, y) for i, y in enumerate(l)]
    return print(l[0])

lucky_candies([5000000,4000000,3000000,2000000,1000000], 9)
```

I tried to change it to something I can read:

```
def lucky_candies(a, k):
    l = [0] + (k-1) * [float('-inf')]
    for x in a:
        for i, y in enumerate(l):
            l = [max(l[(i-x) % k] + x, y)]
    return print(l[0])

lucky_candies([5000000,4000000,3000000,2000000,1000000], 9)
```

But this returns:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new list (called `result`) for every iteration of `a` to hold the new `l`. As an aside, what is the reason for using `return print(l[0])`? You can just `return`.

Try the following:

```
def lucky_candies(a, k):
    l = [0] + (k-1) * [float('-inf')]
    for x in a:
        result = list()
        for i, y in enumerate(l):
            result.append(max(l[(i-x) % k] + x, y))
        l = result
    return l[0]

>>> lucky_candies([5000000,4000000,3000000,2000000,1000000], 9)
9000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Old code gives list `l` of length `k`, while new code immediately makes one-element list `l`, so handling with indices>0 becomes illegal

Append `max(l[(i-x) % k] + x, y)` to new list

Comment: Yes, exactly. Overwritten by one-element list. And I propose to create another list and append items to it.